# How long does it take to cook ground meat on a skillet?

Tags: food-safety, chicken, meat, beef, pork

I was wondering how long it exactly takes to cook ground meat in a skillet on the stove on medium heat for these meats?

1) pork
2) bison 
3) beef
4) chicken

Comment: Hello and welcome to Seasoned Advice! Is this a homework question?

Comment: Are you talking about patties? If so, how thick?

Comment: I assume you mean ground meat, as in separate particles.  In general, I'd advise to cook until the pink is gone.  Cooking over medium to medium-high should yield doneness in 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Because we don't know how hot your skillet is, how much ground meat you use and in which form the meat comes (as a thick patty or loose), [you will have to use thermometer.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/4432/23376) The safe temperature of chicken and pork is the same like the safe internal temperature since there are [bacterica inside the piece of meat](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/5288/23376) and the suggested temperature already regards this.

[Pork: 150 F or 66° C](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/40118/23376)
[Chicken: 170 F or 76°C](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/4432/23376)
[Beef and probably bison, too: 170°C or 76°C](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/2789/23376)

If you want to cook loose ground meat (and measuring the internal temperature is difficult), cook it [until the meat is not red/pink anymore](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/11527/23376).

Comment: @Joe: Uhm, because of these variables I suggested to go by temperature, not by time and in doubt, to cook until the meat isn't pink/red anymore. Maybe I didn't emphasized enough the crucial part due to my mediocre English.

Comment: I think it was more my responding to messages while 1/2 asleep this morning.

Answer (score -3):

You cook any type of meat until no blood or pink is visible. I cook my meat whether it's beef or chicken until done. I do not use a temp stick or gauge to measure the temp. I have been cooking since I was 13, I guess you can say it comes automatic. Over a medium heat I cook ground beef until it is brown, strain excess oil off and that's it.

Comment: While this will generally make things safe, it's misleading. A lot of things are safe already even when some pink remains. (And there's no blood involved at all. [The red in meat is myoglobin in muscle, not hemoglobin in blood.](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24208/why-is-meat-red))