# Is it safe to cook raw meat (beef) and veggies in the same pan?

Tags: food-safety, meat, onions, raw-meat

Is it safe to first make sautéed onions and then cook raw (thawed) beef in the same pan? I plan on cooking the meat thoroughly (no pink), so I figured I should be okay, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you cook the meat thoroughly (i.e. if it reaches a [safe temperature](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/49272/23376)), most pathogens should be dead and it doesn't matter in which order you put the vegetables and the meat in. However, the order *does* matter if you don't want to have your garlic or onions burned while the meat is undercooked or raw vegetables while the meat is overcooking.